# Not able to install rails using rvm on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

I am trying to follow digital ocean blog to install rails on ubuntu 14.04. I have installed it earlier on different systems using same commands but this time it is giving error.

Once I run

`gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3`

I get the following:

```
gpg: requesting key D39DC0E3 from hkp server keys.gnupg.net
?: keys.gnupg.net: Host not found
gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 7: couldn't connect: Success
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

And next when I run:

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails
```

I am getting following:

```
Downloading https://github.com/rvm/rvm/archive/1.29.1.tar.gz
Downloading https://github.com/rvm/rvm/releases/download/1.29.1/1.29.1.tar.gz.asc
Found PGP signature at: 'https://github.com/rvm/rvm/releases/download/1.29.1/1.29.1.tar.gz.asc',
but no GPG software exists to validate it, skipping.

Upgrading the RVM installation in /home/shivraj/.rvm/
stat: cannot stat ‘/<gconf>/ a<entry name='login_shell' mtime='1497974547' type='bool' value='true'/>’: No such file or directory
stat: cannot stat ‘/<gconf>/ a<entry name='login_shell' mtime='1497974547' type='bool' value='true'/>’: No such file or directory
    RVM PATH line found in /home/shivraj/.mkshrc /home/shivraj/.profile /home/shivraj/.bashrc /home/shivraj/.zshrc.
    RVM sourcing line found in /home/shivraj/.profile /home/shivraj/.bash_profile /home/shivraj/.zlogin.
Upgrade of RVM in /home/shivraj/.rvm/ is complete.
```

When I try checking for `rvm list` its not installed, neither has rails.

Comment: Have you tried `source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm` ?

Comment: Check your `gpg` version on Ubuntu. Looks like bug for `gpg < 2` as per this [*discussion*](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/3544)

Comment: Before doing that a long installation is supposed to happen. Thats not happening

Comment: @Pavan I checked its 1.4.16